# PHP class that sorts an ordered integer array with the help of sort() function

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have written down the following for the above question

```
<?php

class sortClass{

  public function __construct(array $arrayPassed){
    return sort($arrayPassed);
    }

}
$newarray=array(11,-2,4,35,0,8,-9);
$sorted =  new sortClass($newarray);
print_r($sorted);

?>
```

And the output is 'sortClass Object()' , I'd like some help to understand why it would not print out the sorted array , When we instantiate a class - the constructor will automatically execute and return what ever it returns right? so why isn;t printing $sorted object printing whats returned in the constructor?

Comment: You cannot return a value from the constructor, the return of using `new ...` is a new object of the class type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a wrapper `class` just to sort, you can  just run `sort` function directly, the issue with your code is, returning in `__constructor`.

I suggest you run it directly like this:

```
<?php
  $newarray = array(11,-2,4,35,0,8,-9);
  sort($newarray);
  print_r($newarray);
?>
```

or this one if you still need a OOP version:

```
<?php

class sortClass{
  private $arrayPassed = [];
  public function __construct(array $arrayPassed){
    $this->arrayPassed = $arrayPassed;
  }

  public function sort() {
    sort($this->arrayPassed);
    return $this->arrayPassed;
  }
}

$newarray = array(11,-2,4,35,0,8,-9);

$sortClass =  new sortClass($newarray);

print_r($sortClass->sort());
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

You misunderstood OOP, you need to learn about it before write code.
I give a workaround just for the idea:

```
class sortClass
{
    public $sorted;

    public function __construct(array $arrayPassed)
    {
        sort($arrayPassed);
        $this->sorted = $arrayPassed;
    }
}

$newarray = array(11, -2, 4, 35, 0, 8, -9);
$sorted = new sortClass($newarray);
var_dump($sorted->sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return anything from a constructor method. You have to create a new public method which return the sorted the value.

```
class MyClass
{
  private $sorted;

  public function __construct(array $input)
  {
     $this->sorted = asort($input);
  }

  public function sortedArray()
  {
     return $this->sorted;
  }
}

$arr = [11, -2, 4, 35, 0, 8, -9];
$sorted = new MyClass($arr);
print_r($sorted->sortedArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

AS **Nigel Ren** explain you can't return from a constructor method. You need a new method to return the sorted the value. Check my code

```
class sortClass{
  private $sortedArray;

  public function __construct(array $arrayPassed){
    $this->sortedArray = asort($arrayPassed);
    }

  public function  getSortedArray(){
     return $this->sortedArray;
  }

}
$newarray=array(11,-2,4,35,0,8,-9);
$sorted =  new sortClass($newarray);
print_r($sorted->getSortedArray());
```

Comment: `sort()` method return boolean since it take argument as reference.